# How to obtain resource group name when using New-AzureRmDeployment and linked ARM template to create a resource group and resource?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

When deploying a linked ARM templated via a master ARM template using the `New-AzureRmDeployment` commandlet, I am getting an error when trying to use the `resourceGroup().name` function and property. The error message is:

```
Unable to process template language expressions for resource
'/subscriptions/<subscriptionGuid>/resourceGroups/Zxy- 
Test/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/storageDeployment' at line 
'29' and column '5'. 'The template function
'RESOURCEGROUP' is not expected at this location.`
```

As an alternative, I have tried using the `resourceId(...)` function without the resource group function call but that gives an incorrect resource ID where the resource group information is missing and does not match the resource ID obtained from the Azure portal.

e.g.

```
"value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName'))]"
```

Result with missing resource group:

```
/subscriptions/<subscriptionGuid>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/linktestdata
```

Here is what I expect, which is also reported by the Azure portal

```
/subscriptions/<subscriptionGuid>/resourceGroups/Zxy-Test/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/linktestdata
```

I have the following `TestMaster.json` and `TestLinked0.json` templates as an example to demonstrate the problem.

**TestMaster.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "linkedTemplateUri": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "URI to the linked ARM template file."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
      "name": "testMasterDeployment",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "location": "West US",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[parameters('linkedTemplateUri')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "tagValues": { "value": {
              "TagA": "A-Tag",
              "TagB": "B-Tag"
          }}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "messageFromMaster00": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "Master-00 reporting"
    },
    "messageFromLinkedTemplate": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": "[reference('testMasterDeployment').outputs.messageFromNestedTemplate]"
    }
  }
}
```

**TestLinked0.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "rgName": {
      "defaultValue": "Zxy-Test",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
      "defaultValue": "West US",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "tagValues": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "storageName": "linktestdata"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "name": "[parameters('rgName')]",
      "properties": {},
      "tags": "[parameters('tagValues')]"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "storageDeployment",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('rgName')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', parameters('rgName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
              "apiVersion": "2017-10-01",
              "name": "[variables('storageName')]",
              "location": "[parameters('location')]",
              "tags": "[parameters('tagValues')]",
              "kind": "StorageV2",
              "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
              }
            }
          ],
          "outputs": {
            "storageAccount": {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "[variables('storageName')]"
            },
            "resourceInfo0": {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName'))]"
            },
            "resourceInfo1": {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName'))]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "messageFromNestedTemplate": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": "[reference('storageDeployment').outputs]"
    }
  }
}
```

The PowerShell used to deploy the ARM templates:

```
$uri = 'https://<containername>.blob.core.windows.net/azure-resource-templates/TestMaster.json'
$linkedTemplateUri = 'https://<containername>.blob.core.windows.net/azure-resource-templates/TestLinked0.json'
New-AzureRmDeployment -Location 'West US' -TemplateUri $uri -linkedTemplateUri $linkedTemplateUri
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have now found the Microsoft documentation that says "The resourceGroup() function is not supported." for subscription level deployments at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/deploy-to-subscription#using-template-functions. The commandlet I am using is `New-AzureRmDeployment`, which is used to deploy resources at the current subscription scope. Looks like I'll need to take a different approach.

Comment: Right, how would it even mean to ask for what resourcegroup a subscription-level deployment is happening in?   It isn't in one.

Answer (score 2):

resourceGroup().name will work too

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29796375)